# Display Parameter value on SSRS Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am very new to SSRS.

I have added one Parameter named Date on SQL Server Report

i have set parameter value from aspx.cs code behind file

i have drown that parameter on ReportHeader and i want display CurrentDate value on that parameter

and i tried `=Join(Parameters!Date.Value,", ")` but it displays `#Error` at runtime.

i also tried `=Join(Parameters!Date.Label,", ")` but it displays Nothing.

Please tell me how to display Parameter value on Report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you are asking.  To display the parameter value on the report, create a textbox on the report and then set it's expression to your parametername.value.

Something like this:

```
=Parameters!Date.Value(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what ur asking ...wheather u need report run date or parameter passing date ....

If u need report date .... follow this 
Drag a textbox onto the report ...page header or footer

and ----> `=Today()`

If u need parameter value(date) what ur passing

Just the `parameters!paraame.value` ...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your correctly you want to do:

```
=Parameters!Date.Value & ", "
```

`&` is the string concatentation operator in SSRS, you must have a space on each side of it FYI